# Object tag css styling for shadow element

Tags: html, css

I have used an image with `<object>` tag. But some larger image showing scrollbar in it.

I need to set the image width to 100px width, so how can we edit the shadow element inside the `<object>` tag?

Tried `width="100"` to the `<object>` but showing image width is more than object tag.

Here is the code:

```html
<object data="//via.placeholder.com/645x400" aria-label="logo" type="image/svg+xml" ></object>
```

Comment: This is impossible as this image is called from another page via object.

Comment: Is there a specific reason to use `<object>` instead of `<img>`?

Comment: @NicoShultz yes.. something regarding fast loading

Comment: @vishnu are you sure about that? I mean it still loads a `img` element just inside its own document

Answer (score -2):

the problem is you are using the generated image and it says the image must be 645 x 400

please use the below code. I have set the image width and height to 100 x 100 .. check the URL

```
<object data="//via.placeholder.com/100x100" aria-label="logo" type="image/svg+xml" ></object>
```

please check the below code pen to get more idea

https://codepen.io/subodha-the-selector/pen/dypEYoe

Comment: Image is the dynamic content.. so it can be any size..